# How to match filename containg datetime values in python

Tags: python

I have got a file with name as 'Entry_Form_25012022_121314' where 25012022 is date in ddmmyyyy format and 121314 is time in hhmmss format.

I need to check if any input file matches this format. The date and time would change for the inputted file however it should follow the same pattern.

I tried using fnmatchcase as below. However this will take any file without the date time patterns too.

import fnmatch

if fnmatchcase('Entry_Form_24012022','Entry_Form_*'):

```
Print('correct')
```

Comment: Why not use `if fileName.startswith('Entry_Form_')`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [fnmatch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html), `[seq]` can be used to match specific characters. In your case, you would want a pattern like this:

```py
import fnmatch

if fmmatchcase(filename, 'Entry_Form_[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]_[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]'):
    # Filename matches
```

However, this solution seems unnecessarily verbose. If you just want to match a string with a pattern, you can use regexes with the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which is also built in.

```py
import re

# This creates the regex for later use.
# It helps with speed if you need to use a regex multiple times.
# If you only need to use a regex once, you can use re.match(pattern, string) directly.
# Backslashes in regexes should be escaped. Otherwise, they may cause an error.
filename_regex = re.compile('^Entry_Form_\\d{8}_\\d{6}$')

# Regex explanation:
# ^                            This matches the beginning of the string
#  Entry_Form_                 This matches the literal string "Entry_Form_"
#             \d{8}            This matches any digit (0-9) exactly eight times
#                  _           This matches the underscore that separates the date and the time
#                   \d{6}      This matches the time
#                        $     This matches the end of the string

if filename_regex.match(filename):
    # Filename matches
```

Comment: do you use `re.compile` instead of just a string so you can combine it with another regex later? I don't see the utility of it otherwise.

Comment: How did you get the nice explanation of the regex? Made it yourself or is it a result from a generator? I couldn't find anything like it on https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/. If it is something automated I would like to use it to add it to the comment when I use `regex` in my code.

Comment: @Johnny `re.compile` is more efficient when using a regex multiple times, since it only parses the regex once. (It doesn't really matter if you're only using one regex, since `re.match` caches recent regexes, but its still good practice.)

Comment: @3DspatialUser I wrote that explanation myself, manually. I don't know if there are any tools that can automatically generate regex explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using slicing and using the datetime module to check if the given date/time is valid or not.

```
import datetime

f_name = 'Entry_Form_25012022_121314'
isValid = True
if f_name.startswith('Entry_Form_'):

    if f_name[-6:].isnumeric():
        try:
            t = f_name[-6:]
            datetime.time(hour=int(t[:2]), minute=int(t[2:4]), second=int(t[4:]))
        except ValueError:
            isValid=False
    else:
        isValid=False

    if f_name[-7] != '_':
        isValid=False      

    if f_name[-15:-7].isnumeric():
        try:
            dt = f_name[-15:-7]
            datetime.date(day=int(dt[:2]), month=int(dt[2:4]), year=int(dt[4:]))
        except ValueError:
            isValid=False
    else:
        isValid=False            
else:
    isValid=False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use re module to check if the filename is right or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).